# Вводные обороты

Tags: запятые

"Надеюсь, он жив" / "Надеюсь, что он жив".

В первом варианте "надеюсь" вводное, а во втором — нет? Просто если его изъять из первого, получится "он жив", а если из второго, то "что он жив", и теряется смысл. Я прав?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Надеюсь, он жив." - здесь могут быть оба варианта (глагол или вводное, что вероятнее):

*(Я) надеюсь, он жив.*

Вводные слова произносятся значительно быстрее. Так автору можно и определить в спорных случаях, чем именно является слово в его предложении.

Второй вариант - не вводное (теряется смысл при изъятии).

Вот так точно вводное:

*Он, надеюсь, жив.*